# Send all local mail to a single external e-mail

Tags: postfix

I am trying to send all local mail to a single external e-mail, using Google's SMTP servers (I got that working following [this nice tutorial)](http://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/).

Using Google's SMTP servers work, as I am able to send mail to external addresses work using mail from mailutils.

The redirection of local mail to the external e-mail does not work. When sending a mail to root from my account test using:

```
echo "Body" | mail -s "Test Postfix To Root" root
```

- I never recieve the message
- Nothing new turns up in /var/log/mail.err
- This turns up in /var/log/mail.log

```
Sep  4 18:48:06 desktop1204test postfix/pickup[5535]: C9326EE26: uid=1000 from=
Sep  4 18:48:06 desktop1204test postfix/cleanup[5702]: C9326EE26: message-id=
Sep  4 18:48:06 desktop1204test postfix/qmgr[5534]: C9326EE26: from=, size=401, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  4 18:48:06 desktop1204test postfix/local[5704]: C9326EE26: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep  4 18:48:06 desktop1204test postfix/qmgr[5534]: C9326EE26: removed
```

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mynetworks = loopback-only
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
## I commented the below two lines out, as they conflicted with the accepted answer
####virtual_alias_domains = localhost.localdomain
####virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

My `etc/aliases`:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
```

My /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
@localhost.localdomin        someone@somewhere.com
```

How can I get it working? I don't want any local mail to arrive locally, they should all go to `someone@somewhere.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished via virtual regexp (/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp)

```
/.+@.+/ someone@somewhere.com
```

then in main.cf:

```
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

and the mapfile:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

That should do the trick for all local mails (otherwise you must specify all addresses on virtual)

Comment: If I do that I get `postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp` (but I will see if I can fix it)

Answer (score 1):

To those who want to send out mail to other domains normally (e.g. on a send-only null client), and have mail to system accounts delivered remotely, you create `/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp`. In it, either map all system accounts that don't have a real inbox to another:

```
/^\(root\|postmaster\|postfix|etc\)@domain\.example$/ person@domain.example
```

or map all accounts that aren't known real inboxes (do not indent the `if`):

```
if /@domain\.example$/
!/^\(person\|anotherperson\|peeps\)@/ person@domain.example
endif
```

This is a *lot* easier if your `myorigin` setting in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is different to your real inbox domains (e.g. a subdomain of `mail.domain.example`) as then you can match everything like so:

```
/@mail\.domain\.example$/ person@domain.example
```

As others said, do not run `postmap` on this file, and delete `/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp.db` if it exists.

Use the new mapping by adding

```
local_recipient_maps =
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

---

I also added

```
root: person@domain.example
```

to `/etc/aliases` and ran the `newaliases` command, but I think Postfix's virtual alias configuration overrides it.